# How to select all of the rows in a matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, sparse-matrix

This might be a trivial question but I have a matrix called `df` of type:

```
<3291x13692 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 279414 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

I just want to select all of the 3291 rows, just the rows. How can I do that in Python 3?

Comment: The question is rather unclear, what would you like to do? Iterate over rows?

Comment: @SonicARG No, I just want to store them in a variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: You not need to disassembly the matrix just to access its members. Since matrices can behave as lists (two-dimensional lists in this case), you can access them directly, such as `df[24]` (for example, to access the 25th row). You can "bookmark" in a variable if you want as `myrow = df[24]`

Comment: I get that. But that's just ONE row. I want to select all 3291 of them, how can I do that?

Comment: Think about this: if you want to _select rows_ is because you are wanting to do _some additional processing_ on it, rather than just store them (BTW, you already have stored them or "selected them" in the variable `df`). The idea of selecting rows for doing nothing does not make sense at all.

Think for example, selecting all the rows in a Excel spreadsheet; if you are doing nothing later, it does not make sense.

Comment: Bro, of course I am going to work with them. But you haven't answered the question of selecting all rows. Do you do something like this df[0:3291]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231188/discussion-between-sonicarg-and-sam-jatt).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `select just the rows`.  All the rows is the whole matrix, which you already have.

Comment: This isn't going to help with the laplacian calculation

Answer (score 0):

According to the conversation we had via instant messaging, the solution to select the rows is:

```py
df[0:3191]
```

A more generic solution (which selects all rows regardless of the quantity), would be:

```py
df[:]
```